# Prove that $G={x\in R^m:\rho_A(x)<\alpha}$ set is open.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, elementary-set-theory

Prove that $G=${$x\in R^m:\rho_A(x)<\alpha$} set is open.$\forall y\in G$ we need to show that $\exists B_r(y),B_r(y)\subset G$.$x \in B_{\frac{\varepsilon}{2}}(y)$, $|x-y|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$,$\rho_A(y)<\alpha.$ $inf|x-a|\leq|x-a|\leq|x-y|+|y-a| $ . I am stuck here because I have only for $\inf|y-a|<\alpha$

$\rho_A(x) = inf_{a \in A}|x-a|$

Also I have that  for every $A \subset R^m$ non-empty subset and $\alpha >0$ number $F=${$x\in R^m:\rho_A(x)\leq\alpha$} set contains $A$ and is closed.

Comment: Show that $|\rho (x)-\rho (y) |\leq \|x-y\|$. This proves continuity of $\rho_A$.

Comment: Use `$\{ x\}$` for $\{x\}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Can you give some hint how show that it's Lipschitz continuous?

Comment: Triangle inequality!